# jQuery to only accept values between 1 and 100 in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I go about only allowing values between 1 and 100 in my HTML table td cells,

Currently, I have a jquery function only allowing numbers,

```js
//only allow numbers in td
$(".allow_only_numbers").keydown(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
        ((e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 86 || e.keyCode == 67) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        return;
    }
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, I only want values ranging from 1-100

The td is content editable and cells I only want to contain such values have a class called allow_only_numbers e.g

```html
<td contenteditable='true' class="allow_only_numbers">-</td>
```

Comment: So you would need to read the textContent and see if the value entered is in that range. If not you need to say an error and handle it. You are not going to be able to really do it while the key is down since you do not know where the user has the cursor in the input.

Comment: the least annoying way to handle this would be when the cell loses focus.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this

```
$(".allow_only_numbers").keydown(function (e) {

if($(".allow_only_numbers").innerText < 100 && $(".allow_only_numbers").innerText >= 1 ) {
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
        ((e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 86 || e.keyCode == 67) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        return;
    }
    else if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
} else alert('number out of range')



});
```